# How to set up SSL in Zookeeper installed in Windows

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I would like to enable SSL in Zookeeper 3.6.1 in windows environment. I have added `ZOOKEEPER_HOME` in environment variable.

ZkServer.cmd:

```
set SERVER_JVMFLAGS="
-Dzookeeper.serverCnxnFactory=org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory
-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.location=C:/apache-zookeeper-3.6.1/ssl/testKeyStore.jks 
-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.password=testpass 
-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.location=C:/apache-zookeeper-3.6.1/ssl/testTrustStore.jks
-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.password=testpass" 
echo on call %JAVA% "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=%ZOO_LOG_DIR%"
"-Dzookeeper.root.logger=%ZOO_LOG4J_PROP%" "%SERVER_JVMFLAGS%"
"-Dzookeeper.log.file=%ZOO_LOG_FILE%"
"-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=cmd /c
taskkill /pid %%%%p /t /f" -cp "%CLASSPATH%" %ZOOMAIN% "%ZOOCFG%" %*
```

When try run zkServer getting following error:

> C:\Users\e092344>zkServer start '-Dzookeeper.serverCnxnFactory' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file. '-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.location' is not recognized as
>   an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   '-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.password' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   '-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.location' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   '-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.password' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   '-Djava.security.properties' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of set SERVER_JVMFLAGS should be in single line string. It should not be in next line.